How do I resize a page to fit an iframe?
So I'm trying to make a website with html/css. There's sidebars on the website I want to remain universal across pages so I don't need to update every page whenever I change the sidebars, so I used iframe to import the sidebars on the pages. However, when the sidebars are taller than the page itself hosting the content, there's these scroll bars on the iframe and the iframe itself is obviously just cut off to the height of the page. Is there any way to change it so the source website is fit to the height of the iframes? Or is that not possible? Also I can't use javascript
I've tried changing the height in the css stylesheet of the iframes. The closest solution I've gotten is just putting in a ton of <br> tags in the main content of each page to fill the size for the iframes to fully expand.

Unfortunately there is no simple solution for this. A parent document cannot adjust the size of an <iframe> so that all its contents will fit without scrolling ... at least not without Javascript.
HTML versions prior to version 5 include the <frame> element which supports exactly what you are wanting to do. However, this element was withdrawn in HTML 5 and not replaced with an equivalent.
Your options are essentially these:

Use a server-side templating language which has the ability for templates to include other templates. Traditional options include PHP, JSP and ASP, but there are also newer options. This is by far the most common solution to this problem.
Use Javascript to fetch the sidebar HTML file from the server (as a string of text) and assign its contents to an empty sidebar placeholder element in each page, using the placeholder element’s innerHTML property. (In this case the sidebar HTML file will not contain a complete HTML document, just the fragment you would include if you were building the sidebar into the parent page.) If you want avoid server-side templating and you have a large site, this is a great option.
Repeat the code for your sidebars in every page (exactly what you are trying to avoid). For small sites, the cost of converting it to server-side templating or Javascript can easily outweigh the cost of maintaining identical sidebar code across multiple pages.
Use an <iframe> in a fixed position in the viewport and allow its content to scroll if it overflows. Not mobile-friendly.
Build your parent document in HTML 4, which does support <frame> ... your child documents can remain as HTML 5. Not mobile-friendly.

